# Where should I install phpDocumentor 2?

Tags: unix, installation, phpdoc

I want to manually install phpDocumentor 2 on Unix [using the installer](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/installation.html).

I have limited knowledge of the command line, but I do have root access. The instructions say to download the installer *to the intended location*. So where should I download/install it to?

I realize I can put it anywhere I want, but I am interested in knowing some standard locations and why one location might be better than another.

Also, will the installer create it's own parent directory? Or should I create that? I'm never clear on that. For example, I don't want to end up with /usr/bin/phpDoc/phpDoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where to Install

If the intention is to install it in a common shared location, `/opt` would be a [good place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20600/62291).

Quoting from [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)

> /opt is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages.

### Parent Directory

The installer for manual installation seems to have disappeared since the question was posted. But according to their [home page](http://www.phpdoc.org/), you can download the  tarball (not the source code!) from GitHub and extract it into your destination directory.

If you open the tarball, you'll see that the top directory is phpDocumentor-2.3.0 (where 2.3.0 is the version). So when you extract that, you'd end up with /path/to/current/dir/phpDocumentor-2.3.0/...

### Consider PEAR

You should consider installing PEAR. PEAR itself is just a package manager. Installing the package manager doesn't install all the optional PEAR packages. It's really easy to install PEAR with a package manager like `yum` or `apt-get`.

There are a couple of **advantages to installing phpDocumentor with PEAR**.

- It's easier to upgrade when there's a new release.
- You can call it with just `phpdoc` instead of `[PHPDOC_FOLDER]/bin/phpdoc.php`

**Installing with PEAR**

If you use the command `pear install PhpDocumentor`, you get the newest version available from the default channel. At time of writing, that's 1.5.0a1 (alpha) which is deprecated.

To get the **newest release**, install it from the phpdoc channel.

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the command below to install the phpdoc.

```
sudo pear install PhpDocumentor
password *****
```

or

```
pear install PhpDocumentor
```

It will be installed on the following path.

```
cd /usr/lib/php/pear/data/PhpDocumentor
```

Type the following command to see the help.

```
phpdoc -h
```

To create the PHP documentation, use the following command.

```
phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -f pathofthefile/sample1.php -t docs
```

Comment: I don't have pear and want to manually install phpDocumentor.

Comment: To install pear on mac go to http://blog.stealth35.com/2011/07/27/install-pear-on-osx-lion.html

Comment: Here is the pear installation guide http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Comment: Thank you for specifying the path PEAR installs it to, this is required for manually overriding with v2.9.0 for supporting PHP 7 which cannot currently be installed using PEAR (you have to install v2.8.5 and then change the files in the director to v1.9.0).